# Surname plural, Wolf becomes The Wolves?

Tags: names

The Simpson family becomes The Simpsons, does that mean I can call a family with surname Wolf, The Wolves or The Wolfs? I don't know if changing letters of someone's surname is appropriate or not.

Comment: Here are several references to people called [Mr. John Child](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mr+john+child%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Are you seriously suggesting that if one of them (and his good lady wife) invited you to dinner, you'd consider telling people you were entertained by the ***Children**?*

Comment: I don't the answer, that's why I'm asking the question here. So I don't know if you were being rhetorical or not.

Comment: You ask them what they want to be called.

Comment: Hi Kuromusha! First of all, welcome to English Language and Usage Stack Exchange. People here do want to help you by answering your questions. However, certain questions are very common, and the answers to them can easily be found at other places. It's not very fun to hear these over and over again, so that's probably why some people are being a bit short or impolite in response to your question. I think you'll find the answer to your question here, already on the site: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39150/pluralization-of-names/39152#39152.

Comment: Another good resource can be found as the first Google result of searching "surname plural": http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-make-family-names-plural

Answer (score 3):

Most likely **the Wolfs**. Because it is a family name it does not have to follow normal pluralisation rules in English.

Comment: Well, this exact same example is in the question tchrist linked to. I don't really see how your answer contributed any new useful information.

Comment: Everything has been asked and answered before somewhere, sometime. If not here, then elsewhere. So why should anyone ask anything?