# Plural for surnames derived from other words?

Tags: nouns, collective-nouns, irregular-plurals

I recently came across a surname in a podcast, called Barleyfoot. In the podcast, his family was referred to as the Barleyfeet. Is this correct? Or should it be Barleyfoots? What about other possible names ending in words like goose, man, cactus etc. whose original words' plurals don't just add an 's' at the end? I'd like to say that a surname is a Proper noun, but if multiple people in a family have it, is it a Proper noun/ Collective noun?

Edit: The question mentioned as similar, does not cite any references for the answers given. Got answer with reference here

Comment: Closely related: [Pluralization of names](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39150/pluralization-of-names)

Comment: A duplicate of: [Surname plural, Wolf becomes The Wolves?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265906/surname-plural-wolf-becomes-the-wolves) and [Pluralization of proper nouns: regular or irregular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81522/pluralization-of-proper-nouns-regular-or-irregular)

Comment: Would the  [Child(s)](http://www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Childs) family be called *the Children*? No... unless it is meant to be jocular, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: J.R.R. Tolkien had also explored this concept. See [here](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Proudfoot_Family).

Comment: The reference cited in Jason Bassford's answer does not specifically mention surnames/last names that are irregular nouns in English. For instance, "The Wolfs family" or "The Wolves family"? The Fish family" or "The Fishes family" or "The Childs family" or "The Children family"?

Comment: Related, but not about surnames: [Bigfoots or Bigfeet?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396425/bigfoots-or-bigfeet)

Comment: Irregularity of a proper name is not irregularity of a noun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From *The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed.), 7.5:

> Most nouns form their plural by adding *s* or—if they end in *ch*, *j*, *s*, *sh*, *x*, or *z*—by adding es.

And from *Chicago*, 7.9:

> Names of persons and other capitalized nouns normally form the plural by adding *s* or *es*. Exceptions, including the last example, are generally listed in Webster’s . . .
>
> Tom, Dick, and Harry; pl. Toms, Dicks, and Harrys
>       the Jones family, pl. the Joneses
>       the Martinez family, pl. the Martinezes
>       the Bruno family, pl. the Brunos
>       Sunday, pl. Sundays
>       Germany, pl. Germanys
>       Pakistani, pl. Pakistanis
>
> but
>
> Romany, pl. Romanies

Strictly according to this guideline, and assuming that there is no entry for *Barleyfoot* in Webster's, the plural should be **Barleyfoots**.

However, the family *itself* is free to refer to itself in whatever manner it wishes. If a family member says, "My name is Tom Barleyfoot, but if you want to refer to my family as a whole, please call us the Dinklemeisters," then so be it.

Even if it makes no sense at all, it's the family that sets their own guidelines for their own names. The point of a proper name, if you're the person who "owns" it, is that you can do whatever you want with it. (Although the more unusual the thing you do with it, the less likely that anybody else will know to use it as you wish them to.)

So, perhaps the person speaking on the podcast actually *knows* that this family prefers to have people refer to them as the *Barleyfeet* rather than the *Barleyfoots*.

Or, perhaps they just made it up because it sounded right to them.

---

**Update**: A comment asked about the plural of proper names that take the form of irregular plural nouns. For instance: *Fish* or *Wolf*.

As proper names, common sense would seem to dictate that they not be treated in the same way as common nouns. However, that's a subjective take on my part. This specific circumstance isn't covered anywhere specifically. So, I guess it falls to individual preference, with the specific people in question having more of a say in it than anyone.

Note, however, that if you add "family" you leave the family name singular. This is shown in section 7.2, as quoted above, where these are equivalent: *the Jones family* and *the Joneses*; *the Martinez family* and *the Martinezes*; and *the Bruno family* and *the Brunos*.

In the same way, even if you're not sure how you *should* pluralize *Fish* or *Wolf*, you can still reword around it: *The Fish family* and *The Wolf family*.

Comment: The reference cited in your answer does not specifically mention surnames/last names that are irregular nouns in English. For instance, should it be "The Wolfs family" or "The Wolves family"; The Fish family" or "The Fishes family";  "The Childs family" or "The Children family"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA With this ambiguity, assuming the family in question can't be asked, use the singular form and add *family* to the end. (You don't use the plural form with *family*.) I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA *sigh* (no coffee yet . . .) Fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

[CONCRETE NOUNS](https://srinagasudha108.wordpress.com/tag/what-is-collective-noun/) are divided into four types:

1. PROPER NOUN
2. COMMON NOUN
3. COLLECTIVE NOUN and
4. MATERIAL NOUN

Surnames are proper nouns.

Barelyfoot is the surname and not Barelyfeet. In order to address more than one person of Barelyfoot family you have to add 's' for making it plural. You can't simply change someone's surname from Barelyfoot  to Barelyfeet, that is also illegal. So, correct way to refer more than one Barelyfoot is Barelyfoots (or Barelyfoot family).

Comment: Surnames are *not* common nouns; they are proper nouns. And *legality* only applies when you are talking about government paperwork, not when you are referring to common usage.