# What is the plural of "Mars"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

What is the plural of Mars? Is it `Marses` or `Mars'` (note the apostrophe)? Or something else?

EDIT: I'm not sure where I got the idea of `Mars'` from. I suppose I was thinking it might be a zero plural where the word doesn't change, like `fish`, and just threw in the apostrophe like certain other oddities do, e.g., `1960's`, pulling 5 `g's` (g-force).

This came up because a certain attack helicopter configuration is called the Mars, and I need to refer to multiple Marses and multiple Neptunes, but at least the latter is clearly plural.

Comment: I agree that "Marses" would be acceptable, but I would avoid it as far as possible - refer to "Mars helicopters", for instance.  You won't be able to avoid "Marses" entirely, but your readers will thank you for keeping it to a minimum.

Comment: Sure, but the trouble is using the same phrase too much. Already in my novel, I've used the words "helicopters", "helis", "choppers", "aircraft", "rotorcraft", "Mantises", and "Marses" so much already. I need as many options as possible to dilute, for lack of a better term, the number of reuses. Plus in many action sequences I have to distinguish between Marses and Neptunes, and 'Marses' and 'Mars + something' is the only way. 'Mars + something' becomes much more wordy much more fast than Marses.

Comment: A Google search for <"the Mars are" -"on Mars" -"and Mars" -"from Mars" -"of Mars"> (I left the filters in by accident after a preliminary search; they are still very useful in removing inanities like "journeys to the Mars are now possible" for some reason) shows that the invariant plural is used for aircraft (The Mars are also equipped to deliver Thermo-Gel) and the family name (The Mars [Bruno et al] Are A Talented Family). This, combined with sumelic's answer, shows that attempts to apply rules-of-thumb to the behaviour of proper nouns are possibly not all that wise.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Bruno Mars has family with the surname "Mars"? That's odd; I assumed he didn't, because Wikipedia says it's a stage name. That aircraft example is great; why don't you post an answer?

Comment: It's a tongue-in-cheek usage by [Mix96](http://mix96buffalo.com/the-mars-are-a-talented-family/) (but they didn't opt for 'Marses').

Comment: ... I've close-voted on POB grounds.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What does POB stand for?

Comment: If these are fictional names in your novel, you might imagine that the Mars helicopters' flight crew would be nicknamed "the Martians" - and the problem is solved (apart from thinking up a similar nickname for the Neptune guys!).

Comment: Isn't it obvious? One Mars - two Mars bars.

Comment: `1960's` and `5 g's` are not correct; it'd be 1950s and 5 gs, or Gs if you were concerned.

Comment: POB: primarily opinion based [answers are inevitable]. Here, the behaviour of proper nouns is notoriously idiosyncratic, and trying to apply a 'rule' may well lead to a non-idiomatic result.

Comment: I disagree, there is only one Neptune. It must "obviously" be missing a possessive apostrophe. If we're talking about parallel universes, then the *Martian* and *Neptunian* planets works for me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As [MT_Head](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277104/what-is-the-plural-of-mars/277110?noredirect=1#comment612524_277104) points out in the comments, you may be able to avoid using a plural form by resorting to phrases such as ""Mars helicopter configurations" or "Mars configurations." But to answer the question that you actually posed:

### Marses?

Even though it sounds a bit funny, *Marses* is certainly one valid plural form. This follows the default English rules for forming a plural, which have us add /ɪz/ ("izz"), spelled "es" (or just "s" if there is already a silent e) after the sounds /s/, /z/, /tʃ/ ("ch"), /dʒ/ ("j"), /ʃ/ ("sh") or /ʒ/ ("zh"). It's conventional to use these rules when the plural of a usually-singular proper noun is needed. (Source: the "Daily Writing Tips" online post "[Plurals of Proper Names](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/plurals-of-proper-names/)" by Mark Nichol. There is also another question on this site that seems particularly relevant: [Pluralization of names](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39150/pluralization-of-names?lq=1))

Here are the examples I've found so far online of *Marses* being used as the plural of *Mars*. (All books cited were accessed through Google Books.)

For the family name "Mars":

- "[Veronica Mars: When both Marses failed](http://sepinwall.blogspot.com/2006/10/veronica-mars-when-both-marses-failed.html)", a post by Alan Sepinwall from his blog *What's Alan Watching?*.
- "You turn up anything more on the Marses?" from [*The Black Ace: A Brad Shade Thriller*](https://books.google.com/books?id=15acY-Bp8fIC&pg=PT163&lpg=PT163&dq=Marses&source=bl&ots=hFnZlt4xRw&sig=ytOY57ZEcwMV6ktfms_5rcGpmsU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwATg8ahUKEwjthPy5jKDIAhXFN4gKHdfRCSU#v=onepage&q=Marses&f=false), by Gare Joyce.

For the god Mars:

- "Like so many little Marses, / With their tilters at their a–s," from "Helter Skelter," a poem by Jonathan Swift, collected in "[The works of the English poets, from Chaucer to Cowper](https://books.google.com/books?id=gbY5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA483&dq=Marses&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBThQahUKEwiWp4LNj6DIAhVLmYgKHfLSByc#v=onepage&q=Marses&f=false)," edited and with prefaces by Samuel Johnson.
- "The ancient patriarchs, afore the flood, [...] become stout Marses, and beget young Cupids." From ["The Alchemist"](https://books.google.com/books?id=v5BMAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA48&dq=marses&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CE4Q6AEwCThQahUKEwi2qJW3kqDIAhUUNogKHQtfA2Q#v=onepage&q=marses&f=false), by Ben Jonson, collected in *The Works of Ben Johnson*, with notes and a biographical memoir by William Gifford.

For the planet Mars:

- "It explores relationships among the Marses seen with the naked eye, through the telescopic lens, and with the mind's eye as well as the various Marses that have been perceived–or created–by scientists, writers, and visual artists[...]" from [*Imagining Mars: A Literary History*](https://books.google.com/books?id=v3TDEDfEPdEC&pg=PR10&dq=marses&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBji-AWoVChMIjOuFy6OgyAIVjSyICh1t3wrt#v=onepage&q=marses&f=false), by Robert Crossley.
- "They had themselves already dreamed Marses more radical than any she could believe in, Marses that were truly independent, egalitarian, just and joyous." From [*Green Mars*](https://books.google.com/books?id=GTX6YdPc954C&pg=PA514&dq=marses&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEsQ6AEwCDi-AWoVChMIjOuFy6OgyAIVjSyICh1t3wrt#v=onepage&q=marses&f=false), by Kim Stanley Robinson.

### Mars?

Thanks to [Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277104/what-is-the-plural-of-mars/277110?noredirect=1#comment612662_277104), it's been brought to my attention that in some contexts, the invariant plural *Mars*, with no apostrophe, has also been used.

In particular, this has been used when referring to the "[Martin Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_JRM_Mars)" flying boats/water bombers/tankers/seaplanes. I'll try to find more citations and examples of this, but this might actually turn out to be the most relevant situation for you, as it's an example from the context of aircraft.

At first I wondered if there might be some convention to never use a distinct plural form of an aircraft name, but from what I can tell there isn't: a pluralized form of the aircraft Martin P5M Marlin, "[Marlins](http://www.navalaviationmuseum.org/attractions/aircraft-exhibits/item/?item=sp-5b_marlin)", is used on the site of the National Naval Aviation Museum (located in Florida in the United States of America).

So it's possible that people simply thought "Marses" sounded wrong in this case.

### Why it doesn't have an apostrophe

It could not be *Mars'* because a single apostrophe is never added to a word to form a plural; this is only ever used for forming possessives.

An apostrophe plus s (*'s*) is also generally only used to form possessives, although besides this it is sometimes used to form plurals in highly restricted circumstances. In a section on [apostrophized plurals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Use_in_forming_some_plurals), the Wikipedia article "Apostrophe" cites *The Oxford Companion to the English Language* (2nd ed., 2018, McArthur, Lam-McArthur, Fontaine) as identifying the following circumstances where *'s* may be recognized as a valid means of spelling a plural form:

- after an abbreviation (I would say, especially one ending in a capital letter or a period)
- after a numeral, or after a symbol
- after a single letter of the alphabet, or certain short words (*do's*)
- Family names (currently not widely considered to be valid)

The only one of these that could apply to *Mars* is the last. Jon Hanna's answer seems to address that case well, and in any case, an attack helicopter configuration name would not be a family name.

### Other options?

Because *Mars* is from Latin, it has a Latin plural form: *Martes.* (When written with macrons—the line-shaped diacritical marks that are optionally used by modern writers to indicate Latin vowel length—the singular and plural nominative-case Latin forms are *Mārs* and *Mārtēs* respectively.) If used as an English word, *Martes* would be pronounced /ˈmɑrtiːz/ (like "MAR-tease", "MART-ease", or "Marty's"). I'm just listing this for fun: I would not advise using this seriously as the plural of *Mars* in English.

Comment: Why is the Latin plural highly inadvisable? I think it's rather nice.

Comment: @Cerberus: Because then you either have to use the inconsistent "Martes and Neptunes," or you have to use the technically incorrect "Martes and Neptuni" (technically incorrect because "Neptuni" is properly the plural of "Neptunus" rather than of "Neptune).

Comment: Ah. I am at least glad that you have thought about it.

Comment: 'This follows the default English rules for forming a plural' implies that there are rules rather than conventions. Nichol restricts himself to 'time-honored convention' and concedes that some plurals are perverse. Here, the people using the plural form can call the tune. Proper nouns do not follow rules as closely as common nouns.

Comment: @sumelic There is not one 'English method of forming plurals', even for common nouns. _Buffalo_ (the common noun) has three plural forms. I'm not sure how many of these would be used for the proper noun usage (there are over 20 places with this name in the US alone).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Sorry, I guess I'm not writing this clearly enough. I'm not trying to say there is only one method. I'm saying there is only one *default* method. It's much more common and productive than the others. "Buffalos" and "Buffaloes" are just alternate spellings. Though you have a point that zero-plural (like "Buffalo") is somewhat common and productive as well; but it is still less-used and has more restricted contexts of use (mostly animals, ethnonyms, and loanwords from foreign languages).

Comment: '[T]he correct form' should be at best 'a correct form'. I can't find any example of the usage on the internet, but surely it has appeared in some training manual or the like. Usage determines acceptability. // Some authorities (and/including Lynne Truss) say that the pure plurals ex's and do's are permissible, being the lesser of two or more evils.

Comment: Thanks I will go with "Marses". See my comment from the OP for why "Mars helicopters" just won't cut it most of the time.

Comment: Mars is modelled on say Winters ==> Winters, used quite frequently by eg Mr X Winters and family on the internet {eg [here](https://www.wattpad.com/132682252-the-players%27-sister-meet-the-winters)}, probably because Winterses sounds outlandish outside Tolkien. // We went to three works do's last year.

Comment: I thought with words ending with s (especially names) you were allowed to use the apostrophe for the plural?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: It's hard to find a perfect analogy to *Mars*. I don't think *Winters* : *Winters* is one, because "winter" already exists as a singular word, so the "s" can be interpreted as a plural suffix. But "mar" is not a related form to "Mars." Unfortunately, very few singular words end in /rz/; the only other one I can find is "furze," which is mostly used as a mass noun and seems to have derived from a plural form historically.

Comment: @RoseofWords I'll agree that 'apostrophes are never used to form pure plurals' qualifies as a rule, the only exceptions (according to some authorities) in normal usage being the two I've mentioned and perhaps a couple of others.

Comment: You probably have a good point about the (false) plural interpretation with the (some at least often treated as invariant) surnames Winters, Brains, Rides, Rakes, Guns, Abrahams, Andrews, Johns etc, especially as we're probably stuck with Aldises, Antrobuses and Ballesteroses etc: but the 'rule' is becoming rather unwieldy. I've found a Mr Bees in the telephone directory; a swarm would be inconvenient. And Jenkinses, Carrutherses and Davieses don't exactly trip off the tongue.

Comment: I think you've made your point...

Comment: I think the difference between "Mars" and "Marlin" in terms of pluralization is that "Marlin" doesn't already end in an 's'.  Also "marlin" is a kind of bird, which is very commonly pluralized as "marlins", so it has a built-in pluralization.  "Mars" doesn't have something so obvious, hence this whole question...

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure where I got the idea of Mars' from.

Early in the last century, perhaps.

It did once used to be acceptable (and earlier still, quite the done thing) to use an apostrophe when pluralising proper names, especially if they end in *s*, and so *Mars's*. You may have seen enough *Jones's* etc. to half-remember it and come up with *Mars'* instead of *Mars's*.

The form is beyond old-fashioned though, to the point where it is probably not really acceptable today. Go with *Marses*.

Or dodge the issue and go with "Mars configurations".

Comment: I was just about to ask, well what about the *Jones's*? I'm old; I was taught by people raised at that time. *Joneses* to me is yo-nes-is. One out of five Google hits (100K vs 400k) for "keeping up with the [Jones family]" includes *Jones's*. It's no wonder why I always 'seem' to get this wrong.