# Pluralizing a last name: Soloniewicz's, Soloniewiczs, Soloniewiczes?

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, apostrophe, names

Say my last name is Soloniewicz and I'm writing a holiday card. Is it:

1. Happy holidays from the Soloniewicz's
2. Happy holidays from the Soloniewiczs
3. Happy holidays from the Soloniewiczes

I'm leaning towards the number three, but looking for input.

Comment: Happy holidays from the number three? ;-)

Comment: I guess my brain skipped a beat!

Comment: "Wesołych świąt z Soloniewiczów"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pluralization of names](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39150/pluralization-of-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not option 1 (as an apostrophe does not belong here). Option 3 is closest to what one would actually say, so of the choices, is the one to choose. But still, it's an awkward word, so it's worth considering an alternative, such as—

> Happy holidays from the Soloniewicz family.

Comment: Right on, thanks bud. I knew option 1 was out but thought I would throw it out there anyways. I recommended an alternative to avoid it, but they're stubborn and really wanted to figure it out. I think they'll go with option three. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: No probs. Glad I could help. :-) Just had a look at the Chicago manual, and basically -s and -es are options, but I think visually -es is clearer in this case. Anything already ending in -s or -z looks a bit awkward with another -s bolted straight on.