# Pluralizing an irregular family name

Tags: grammatical-number

I have a doubt about the pluralization of irregular family names. What if the family name is an irregular plural form like "mice"? Should you say "the Mice" or "the Mices"?

Comment: I would say "the Mices".  (Unless I was joking around, but I never do that.)

Comment: 1. [Pluralizing a last name: Soloniewicz's, Soloniewiczs, Soloniewiczes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292230) 2. [Q: How to pluralize a last name like Thomas](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215184) 3. [Pluralization of names](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39150)

Answer (score 2):

The plural is regular, even if the surname would (if it were a word) be a noun with an irregular plural. So Mr. & Mrs. Mouse and family are the Mouses, Mr. & Mrs. Foot and family are the Foots, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You definitely wouldn't say "the Mice," it sounds like actual mice. You could say "the Mice family" or "Mr. Mice and his family."

Comment: If you are referring to the unmarried females of the family the correct form used to be " the Misses Mice" but I doubt that anyone uses that these days. It still appears in books of etiquette.

Comment: @JeremyC that is correct but it is not limited to names that happen to sound like a plural. You would do the same thing with any family name- leave it unpluraled after a plural identifier. Such as “The Doctors Smith” or “the Brothers Karamazov”