# Pluralizing a first name

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, names, style-manuals, headline-english

In a social media post, a movie streaming site referred to multiple actresses with the same first name of “Jennifer” without repeating the name each time. Instead, they pluralized Jennifer and the caption read, “Jennifers Aniston, Coolidge and Lopez.” Is this acceptable, as in, is that proper grammar? I believe it is, or at the very least understood what they were doing.

Comment: What do you mean "is this acceptable?" To whom? This is not curated writing. It's just random monkeys typing random things.

Comment: Plus it's headlinese for limited space.

Comment: “Acceptable” as in “is it proper grammar?” Would a writing/English prof say “X nope, that makes no sense.” The same as if someone screwed up capitalization or possession rules. I understand it’s social media and I understand in general people don’t care for grammar anymore. I was simply curious.

Comment: I'd guess it is supposed to be humorous (at least in a mild way), which depends on it being understandable but a little non-standard. Not sure how I can prove this to the standard of an SE answer.

Comment: A comparable usage: _Messrs_ (from the French _Messieurs_) used to be used as the plural of _Mister_, so you would see things like "Messrs Smith, Brown and Johnson were present". _Mesdames_ was used similarly for ladies.

Comment: Thanks for that insight, Kate!

Comment: *The **brothers Grimm and Karamazov** can easily be differentiated on the basis that the former were real, the latter fictional*. I think that's a perfectly acceptable "utterance", but I wouldn't like to say whether the *written* form "should" capitalise ***Brothers***.

Comment: Likely dupe: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39150/pluralization-of-names

Comment: It's proper to pluralize a first name. However, I might be quite insulted if they grouped me with two others and we all had different last names.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pluralization of names can take the form cited in the question. It's unusual to actually identify people that way, as opposed to referring to a name itself, but pluralization is not ungrammatical. For example:

*There were three Davids at the party.*

*Our Sues are Sue Smith and Sue Jones.*

*The U.S. has had multiple Johns as president: Johns Adams and Kennedy.*