# What is the plural of "Santa Claus"?

Tags: grammatical-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Family Name Pluralization](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7469/family-name-pluralization)

What is the plural of *Santa Claus*? It would be *Santa Clauses*, right? I started with *Santa Claus'* but that's obviously not correct.

Comment: Santae Clausen?

Comment: *Santas Claus*? *Fathers Christmas*?

Comment: There is only one Santa Claus. The simulacra you see at malls everywhere are impostors, who promise toys but don't deliver. I know this from bitter experience.

Comment: @Robusto - May I disagree?  My local shopping mall always hires three Santa Clauses to work different shifts over the Christmas period.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the linked one; the "Claus" in "Santa Claus" did not originate as a surname, even if some English speakers have re-parsed it as one. Therefore, it's not clear if rules for surname pluralization should apply in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plural of *Santa Claus* is *Santa Clauses*. See this [guide](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node21.html#SECTION00062000000000000000) on unusual plurals for example.

Comment: But that's the same as the plural of 'Santa clause'.

Comment: I was thinking of a heading or a title - or speech.

Comment: @BarrieEngland, why does that matter in this particular case? (*Stones and Stones* can be a tittle of an article about angry fans throwing stones at Rolling Stones)

Comment: @Unreason: I don't think it does matter. I was being gerish.

Answer (score 1):

Santa Clauses. Since Santa Claus is a proper noun, it's capitalized, thus differentiating it from Santa clauses, which is maybe where you're getting confused. Other than that, it's up to your discretion to make the distinction. That's the English language for you...