# How do I pluralize a name ending in "y"?

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, names, proper-nouns, surnames

Frequently when I refer to or address a family, I do so by pluralizing their last name, e.g., The Smiths, or The Ramones. But suppose I want to address a family whose last name ends in a "y", e.g., Kennedy. Normally in English, I reflexively change the "y" to an "ies" when pluralizing words in this form, but as a proper noun, I'm not sure this is the right thing to do. On the other hand, The Kennedys doesn't seem right either--the "dys" looks like it would lead to a dysfunctional prononciation. I'm also pretty sure an apostrophe belongs nowhere near here.

So how do I properly pluralize a name ending in a "y"?

Comment: Consider ***The Dead Kennedies***.

Comment: If you live in the Rocky Mountains, you live in the Rockies, not the Rockys.

Comment: And consider [The Kennedys.](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/americanexperience/films/kennedys/)

Comment: If my last name were *Bellman*, the plural wouldn't be *Bellmen*. Just add an 's'.

Comment: Related: [Family name pluralization](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7469/family-name-pluralization).

Comment: @tchrist: For the benefit of readers, i'll repeat what i pointed out below: the band themselves spell it [Dead Kennedys](http://www.deadkennedys.com/).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**It seems that the current consensus is “don’t change” (-ys).**

Swan 2005 cautiously says that "proper nouns *usually* [emphasis mine - Alex B.] have ys".

the Kennedys (not the Kennedies)

There’s a punk band, *Dead Kennedys* http://www.deadkennedys.com/; there’s also aTV show, *The Kennedys*.

*the Willoughbys*

*the Wolfs (not the Wolves)*

*the Henrys*

*the two Germanys*

*Februarys*

*Marys (not Maries)*

Huddleston and Pullum 2002 give the following rule *for proper nouns*: “**the base always remains unchanged in both speech and writing**” (p. 1595).

I was able to find one reference only (Chalker 1992 in *The Oxford companion to the English language*) that argues for the form *two Maries*.

The majority of grammars argue for “Marys”:

*the three Marys* (The Oxford guide to English usage, p. 40)

*the little Marys* (A comprehensive grammar of the English language, 1985)

*three Hail Marys* (The Cambridge guide to English usage, 2004).

Google “both Marys”, “both Maries”, “two Marys”, and “two Maries”. By all means, the unchanged form (Marys) is much more common.

A note on *the Rocky Mountains (Rockies)*. Its derivation is **not** a Rocky =>the Rockies.

Re: Tony Awards (Tonys or ?Tonies). [Its official website](http://www.tonyawards.com/en_US/index.html) uses "Tonys."

The variant "Typhoid Marys" is also more common than "Typhoid Maries."

Comment: That it’s *the Wolfs* not **the Wolves* I find especially interesting.

Comment: There is of course the extra little twist that ‘two Marys’ means two girls called Mary, while ‘two Maries’ means two girls called Marie. (Edit: I see this was mentioned by GEdgar already.)

Answer (score 9):

In general you should just add "s".
The Oxford Companion to the English Language mentions occasional exceptions for illustrious names  : the Ptolemies, the two Maries.

Comment: Why do some proper nouns inflect normally but others do not?  Do you really expect there to be two Royal Academys?  That looks very wrong.

Comment: I can think of lots of names that go from **-y > -ies** in the plural. It doesn’t look right to have **-ys** in English.  Kennedies, Tonies, Peabodies, and Maries all come to mind.

Comment: I grew up with a family whose surname was Murphy.  Everyone called them the Murphies.  I’m quite sure that Murphys would not have gone over at all. And I said "two Royal Academys looks very wrong", which isn't quite the same as saying that you were very wrong.

Comment: The example used [here is *Murphy*.](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/apostrophes/tips-on-apostrophes-with-names/)

Comment: Dear @tchrist,  you have a point with the Murphys: if a family decides how they want their name to be pluralized, it would be quite rude not to take their wish into account. The more usual case, I suppose, would be when you don't know the people in question, which is probably what Ray wants to know. By the way I find it fascinating how grammatical questions get mixed up with questions of gracious behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

tchrist may hear of *Typhoid Maries*, but I don't.  Here in the US, the two names *Mary* and *Marie* are different, and pronounced differently.  Two *Maries* I would interpret as two people named *Marie*.

[image]

[NGRAM link](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Typhoid%20Marys,Typhoid%20Maries&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3)

Similarly, *Tonys* and *Peabodys* are more frequent that their *ies* versions.

Comment: What do you think is more sensible: there having once been two Germanys, or two Germanies? I cannot imagine the former.

Comment: Don’t trust ngrams.  Try this alternate google service [here](http://googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=typhoid+maries&word2=typhoid+marys), which shows a 1:2 ratio.

Comment: Improve your imagination:  try "two Germanies" and "two Germanys" on Googlefight.  http://googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=two+germanies&word2=two+germanys

Comment: @tchrist: with your Germanys-Germanies  you remind me of François Mauriac's quip  just after WWII: *J'aime tellement l'Allemagne que je suis heureux qu'il y en ait deux.* (For non francophone readers : *I like Germany so much that I am happy  there are two*). Und ich bin sicher, dass  deutsche Leser genug Humor haben, um den Scherz auch zu genießen!

Comment: @tchrist, Googlefight is fun, but it only scans the web, which is a very lopsided view of English.  Ngrams is at least normalized data on stuff that has been proofread. Considering that it contains lots of fiction, it presumably contains colloquial usages, though at a lower rate than standard usages.  The web is probably the other way around.

Answer (score 6):

You can’t change someone’s name. Kennedy is Kennedy is Kennedy, so you have to write Kennedys. French goes further and won’t even add an ‘s’. It’s ‘les Kennedy’, but French has the advantage of a plural form of the definite article.

Comment: Then why do we hear of Typhoid Maries then? And what about the band The Dead Kennedies? If you had Mr Bugs Bunny and Mrs Babs Bunny over for dinner, you’d be having the Bunnies over. If someone wins more than one Peabody or Tony Award, they’re said to have several Peabodies or Tonies. So it seems it’s ok after all.  You aren’t “changing their name”.  You’re merely applying the regular rules of English spelling to regular inflections. Nothing odd about that at all. Next you’ll say you don’t add “-es” to proper nouns that end in “s”, because that would “change their name”.

Comment: @tchrist: 'Spose I'm just saying what I'd do. I tend not to have rabbits for dinner, not even to eat.

Comment: Dear @tchrist, I must concede that  your counter-example about the Bunnies plunges me in an abyss of reflection.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg If you think Bunnies are bad, consider that  I live in the Rocky Mountains, which are customarily called the Rockies, never the *Rockys.

Comment: http://www.nytimes.com/2009/05/03/opinion/03kristof.html

Comment: Dear @tchrist: oh, we certainly agree about the Rockies. (And from what I've heard the sceneries are real beauties there...)

Comment: @JLG My googlefu yields 2 typhoid marys for each 1 typhoid maries.

Comment: @tchrist, What would the plural of Marie be, then?

Comment: @JLG It’s the same, just as *bases* serves as the plural both of *base* and of *basis* alike. There’s no problem with that sort of thing in English, I’m sure you’ll agree.

Comment: Ok Barrie, I see your point.  Two people named *Fairchild* are not **Fairchildren*. :)

Comment: @tchrist: Others have addressed Typhoid Marys; Muscle Marys seem to pluralise the same way. It's the [Dead Kennedys](http://www.deadkennedys.com/). An ex-girlfriend has a friend called Laura Bunny; i think would refer to her family as the Bunnys, but i'd have to ask her to be sure.

Comment: @tchrist Apparently, there is a difference of opinion over whether it should be 'Proudfoots' or 'Proudfeet'. This was highlighted by some linguist or other. And as for _Bagginses_ ....

Answer (score 2):

I'm short on rep so can't leave a comment, but just want to point out that "Bunny" and "Rocky" are special, in that they are "properizations" of common nouns/adjectives. So "The Rockies" or "The Bunnies" could be considered a special subset of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to refer to the family members collectively, you can sometimes sidestep this by saying "The Smith family", although it can sound a little too formal in some situations.

Comment: While sidestepping the problem may be good advice, you haven't answered this actual question.